# Question get closed (with misunderstanding)

Tags: support

The question [Where does RNA polymerase II CTD bind to the RNA modification proteins](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/97024/where-does-rna-polymerase-ii-ctd-bind-to-the-rna-modification-proteins) has too much question in a single question, then I split some content to another question [How does RNA polymerase II CTD bind to the RNA modification proteins?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/97034/how-does-rna-polymerase-ii-ctd-bind-to-the-rna-modification-proteins), they are different questions.

Now the old one get cloesed which indeed contains my main question, and the new one get retained (and downvoted)

Comment: Ok, I assumed that the new version was the more recent one. I can also reopen this one and close the other one. But as I wrote: Please use the edit function and do not use entirely identical subject lines. Once edited, I will reopen.

Comment: @Chris Should I split the question or not? A comment suggest that my question contain too many questions. What do you mean by "subject line" - the content or the title? Please notice that the main content are different even the first line (introduction) are the same

Comment: I mean the title. It should be possible to discriminate both questions.

Comment: Now both are reformed.

Comment: Both are open now, let's wait for some answers.